# How to get browser back button to work in single page navigation

Tags: jquery, browser, back

I am trying to make single page navigation work on a simple website. Basically I am just showing one div and hidding the remaining pages. Clicking link or buttons shows a new div and hides the previous div/page. My problem is how to get the browser back button to work??
This is a simplied version of the code so far 
HTML:

```
<body>
      <!--Main page-->
      <div id="main-page">
            <a href="#page-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display: block;margin-left:33%; margin-right: 33%; margin-bottom: 50px;" role="button" id="nav-to-page-1-btn">
            <a href="#page-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display: block;margin-left:33%; margin-right: 33%; margin-bottom: 50px;" role="button" id="nav-to-page-2-btn">Page 2</a>
       </div>
       <div id="page-1">
            <a href="#main-page" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display: block;margin-left:33%; margin-right: 33%; margin-bottom: 50px;" role="button" id="back-to-main-page-">Main Page</a>
       </div>
       <div id="page-2">
            <a href="#main-page" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display: block;margin-left:33%; margin-right: 33%; margin-bottom: 50px;" role="button" id="back-to-main-page-">Main Page</a>
       </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    doOtherStuff();
    performNavigation();
 });
function performNavigation()
{
    //set intial state
    $("#main-page").show();
    $("#page-1").hide();
    $("#page-2").hide();

    $("#back-to-main-page-btn").bind("click", function () {
            location.reload();
            //Would like to avoid having to reload the page
        });


    $("#nav-to-page-1-btn").bind("click", function () {
            $("#main-page").hide();
            $("#page-1").show();
            $("#page-2").hide();
    });

    $("#nav-to-page-2-btn").bind("click", function () {
            $("#main-page").hide();
            $("#page-1").hide();
            $("#page-2").show();
    });

//Todo: make browser back button work   
}
```

Perhaps my approach is wrong is wrong? are there better ways than hide and showing div's, which will make it easier to get the browser back button to work?

Comment: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the History API or history.js to tell the browser the state of the page changed.

That also means you should bind your page changes to URLs so that for example `#page-1` can be access via `www.yourdomain.com/page1`.

I can recomment this tutorial how to start with the History API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history